# Error when using `coord_trans(y = "log10")` in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use `coord_trans()` to transform the coordinate of my figure to log10, but I get an esoteric error.

**Code**:

```
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = gapminder,
       mapping = aes(x = year,
                     y = gdpPercap * pop)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
  coord_trans(y = "log10")
```

**Error**:

> ```
> Error in if (zero_range(range)) zero_width else diff(range) : 
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
> In addition: Warning message:
> In trans$transform(limits) : NaNs produced
> ```

Comment: It works with `geom_point` so it must be specific to `geom_smooth`. It appears the problem is that the confidence interval goes below 0. It would work with `geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE)`. It's unclear what you would want it to look like with the confidence intervals though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution to plot it, try

```
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = gapminder,
       mapping = aes(x = year,
                     y = log10(gdpPercap * pop))) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Nicolás Velásquez! I am actually not looking for a solution to plot it. Just trying to wrap my head around scales and coordinates and ran into this issue. Thanks!